# PhpStorm can not save files, unable to open the file for writing

Tags: php, laravel, docker, phpstorm

I'm working on a project in Laravel and using Docker. I don't know why I suddenly get this error message from PhpStorm.

I ran `sudo chmod 777 -R my-project-name` but I keep getting the error message.

How can I fix that?

The error message:

[image]

Docker file:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

[image]

Comment: What do you get if you do `ls -l` on both that file and the parent directory when you get that error?

Comment: I don't undrestand what u exactly mean. If I run ls -l, I get a list of al files with my ubuntu username

Comment: Use the command on the file that's giving the error. The `app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php` as well as `app/Http/Controllers`

Comment: If I run: ls -l app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php, I get: ```-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 121 Oct 25 18:34 app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php ``` and When I run: ls -l app/Http/Controllers, I get ``` -rw-r--r-- 1 mohsen mohsen 121 Oct 25 15:24 AuthController.php~````
```-rwxrwxrwx 1 mohsen mohsen 361 Sep 20 15:19 Controller.php```
```-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   121 Oct 25 18:34 TestController.php```
```-rw-r--r-- 1 mohsen mohsen 121 Oct 25 18:34 TestController.php~ ```

Comment: That indicates that for some reason the file belongs to root rather than your username. You can fix that (for all files) with `chown mohsen * -R` (run this in your project directory)

Comment: I get the same problem. Can I give the permission somewhere in the dockerfile? How? I am new in Docker

Comment: You can also try `chown -R mohsen:mohsen *` to make sure the group changes as well. Otherwise, you'll have to figure out why root keeps changing the owner.

Answer (score 1):

When you run docker-compose
It will creat a project with ower is root or name for docker set. You will see lock icon in the folder. Current, you are only a visitor. But you always change files that you are not owner. How can do it?
When start you can run.
`sudo chmod 777 -R my-project-name` 
But it is not good. Because everyone can change your file without permission.
Solution:

1. check permission your file:
   `getfacl [relate_path_your_file]/TestController.php` or `ls -l [relate_path_your_file]/TestController.php`
   [enter image description here][1]
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T85A.png
2. Add your account to group of this project
   `sudo adduser {USER-NAME-HERE} {GROUP-NAME-HERE}`
3. Add write permission for group user
   `sudo chmod g+w [relate_path_your_file]/TestController.php`
   Right now your group user can edit file, include you
   If you want to change others file, redo step 3 with path your file.
   If not work, reopen phpStom